# Placement of contents within table

Tags: tables, positioning

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt
]{article}

\usepackage[
  a3paper,
  landscape,
  hmargin = 3cm,
  vmargin = 0cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{
  multirow,
  ragged2e
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE
]{siunitx}


\def\mlr{0.8}
\newcommand*\mc[2]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mcA[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}
\newcommand*\mcB[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{p{2cm}|}{#2}}
\newcommand*\afsnit[1]{\textsl{#1}}
\newcommand*\farve{\cellcolor{black}}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{\raisebox{-1ex}{#1}}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large
 \begin{tabular}{
         |>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{2.3cm}
    *{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.15cm}}
    *{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.3cm}}
    *{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.15cm}}
   *{10}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.3cm}}|
 }
  \hline
     \textbf{Tid}
   & \mcA{2}{\SI{75}{\minute}}
   & \SI{15}{\minute}
   & \mcA{2}{\SI{45}{\minute}}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
     \textbf{Sted}
   & \mcA{2}{Bog}
   & Mappe
   & \mcA{2}{Bog/comp.}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
     \multirow{3}{2cm}{\huge\bfseries Uge 8--9}
   & \mcB{2}{\includegraphics[width = 2.5cm]{kontext.jpg}}
   &         \includegraphics[width = 2.5cm]{tabel.jpg}
   & \mcB{2}{\includegraphics[width = 2.5cm]{rumgeometri.jpg}}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \cline{2-16}
   & \mcB{2}{\afsnit{Kasser til markedet}}
   & Tabel- tr{\ae}ning
   & \mcB{2}{Under- s{\o}gelse}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \cline{2-16}
   & $1$--$4$
   & $5$--$9$
   & 
   & $116$
   & $117$
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Amalie
   &  
   &  
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Images:

[image: kontext]

[image: tabel]

[image: rumgeometri]

**Questions/problems**

- I would like the three images all to be placed at the top of their respective cells.
- I would like the text in the cells just under the cells with the images to be placed at the top of their respective cells.
- I would like the text `Uge 8--9` to be vertically centered within the three cells in the first column.

Tables are not my speciality at all so I really don't know where to begin when trying to fix the 'problems'.

**Update**

After using Zarko's code, it's almost perfect;

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  danish
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  a3paper,
  landscape,
  hmargin = 0.2cm,
  vmargin = 0cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{
  multirow,
  tabularx,
  ragged2e
}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[
  export
]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[
  table
]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype}


\def\mlr{0.37}
\newcommand*\mcA[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}
\newcommand*\mcB[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{p{2cm}|}{#2}}
\newcommand*\afsnit[1]{\textsl{#1}}
\newcommand*\navn[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand*\farveA{\cellcolor{gray}}
\newcommand*\aktivitet[3]{%
  \mcA{#1}{%
    \includegraphics[
      width = #2,
      valign = t,
      margin = 0pt 3pt 0pt 0pt
    ]{example-image-#3}%
  }%
}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
 \begin{tabular}{
        |>{\RaggedRight}p{2.3cm}
   *{2}{|>{\Centering}p{1.3cm}}
        |>{\Centering}p{2.3cm}
   *{2}{|>{\Centering}p{1.3cm}}
        |>{\Centering}p{2.4cm}
        |>{\Centering}p{1.6cm}
        |>{\Centering}p{2.8cm}
        |>{\Centering}p{2cm}
        |>{\Centering}p{3.5cm}
   *{5}{|>{\Centering}p{0.5cm}}
        |>{\Centering}p{2.4cm}|
 }
  \hline
     \textbf{Tid}
   & \mcA{2}{\SI{110}{\minute}}
   & \SI{30}{\minute}
   & \mcA{2}{\SI{80}{\minute}}
   & \SI{50}{\minute}
   & \mcA{2}{\SI{90}{\minute}}
   & \SI{30}{\minute}
   & \SI{180}{\minute}
   & \mcA{5}{\SI{30}{\minute}}
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
     \textbf{Sted}
   & \mcA{2}{Bog}
   & Mappe
   & \mcA{2}{Bog/comp.}
   & \navn{Mat.Fessor}
   & \mcA{2}{Bog}
   & 
   & \navn{MinUddannelse}
   & \mcA{5}{Udendørs}
   & Kasse \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
     \multirow{7}{=}{\huge\bfseries Uge 9--10}
   & \aktivitet{2}{2cm}{10x16}
   & \aktivitet{1}{2cm}{10x16}
   & \aktivitet{2}{2cm}{1x1}
   & \aktivitet{1}{1.6cm}{10x16}
   & \aktivitet{2}{2cm}{10x16}
   & \aktivitet{1}{2cm}{1x1}
   & \aktivitet{1}{2cm}{10x16}
   & \aktivitet{5}{1.8cm}{10x16}
   & \aktivitet{1}{2cm}{1x1} \\[\mlr ex]
  \cline{2-17}
   & \mcB{2}{\afsnit{Kasser til markedet}}
   & \RaggedRight Tabel\-træning
   & \mcB{2}{Undersøgelse}
   & \RaggedRight Trænings\-opgaver
   & \mcB{2}{\afsnit{Breddeopgaver}}
   & \RaggedRight Skak
   & \RaggedRight \afsnit{Vand som en ressource}
   & \mcB{5}{Lufter}
   & \RaggedRight Ekstra\-opgaver \\[\mlr ex]
  \cline{2-17}
   & $1$--$4$
   & $5$--$9$
   & 
   & $116$
   & $117$
   & 
   & $1,4,7,8$
   & $2,3,10,11,15$
   & 
   & 
   & \mcB{5}{}
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Amalie
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Arthur
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Asker
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Augusta
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Benjamin
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Camilla
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Carla
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Casper
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Cecilie
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Jessica
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Kasper
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Katrine
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Lea
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Liv
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Lukas
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Maria
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Marius
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Mathilde
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Mikkel B.
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Mikkel K.
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Mikkel P.
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Mille
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Philip
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Shiyar
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Sofie
   &  
   &  
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Solveig
   & 
   & 
   & \farveA
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & 
   &  \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The only small glitch is, that I get two

> Overfull `\hbox`

warnings and I'm not sure how to get rid of them.

Comment: Suggestion for the example: use `example-image-10x16`, `example-image-16x10` and `example-image-1x1` instead of `kontext`, `tabel` and `rumgeometri`. Most people will have the `mwe` package, so those images are readily available, and one doesn't have to go to the extra trouble of saving three images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have more issues in your *mwe*:

- mismatch in defining and use `multicolumn` cells.
- estimating number of lines span with `multirow`
- etc (i focus only to first two problems)

[image]

is this what you looking for?

made changes in your *mwe*

- for image are is used `\mcA` instead `\mcB`
- image width is reduced to 2cm (from 2,5 cmm what is wider than prescribed `\mcB` width)
- added is package `adjustbox` by which is changed image baseline from bottom to top and added margins around of image
- for `multirow` cell is used option `{=}` which overtake column formating
- number of line spanned by `multirow i estimate that are 9 (3  from text, 6 from height of images)
- added is `\extrarowheight` for better vertical spacing of cells' contents

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a3paper,
            landscape,
            hmargin = 0.2cm,
            vmargin = 0.5cm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\def\mlr{0.8}
\newcommand*\mc[2]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mcA[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}
\newcommand*\mcB[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{p{2cm}|}{#2}}
\newcommand*\afsnit[1]{\textsl{#1}}
\newcommand*\farve{\cellcolor{black}}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{\raisebox{-1ex}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\large
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
 \begin{tabular}{
         |>{\RaggedRight}p{2.3cm}
    *{2}{|>{\Centering}p{1.15cm}}
    *{1}{|>{\Centering}p{2.3cm}}
    *{2}{|>{\Centering}p{1.15cm}}
   *{10}{|>{\Centering}p{2.3cm}}|
 }
  \hline
     \textbf{Tid}
   & \mcA{2}{\SI{75}{\minute}}
   & \SI{15}{\minute}
   & \mcA{2}{\SI{45}{\minute}}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
     \textbf{Sted}
   & \mcA{2}{Bog}
   & Mappe
   & \mcA{2}{Bog/comp.}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
     \multirow{9}{=}{\huge\bfseries Uge 8--9}
   & \mcA{2}{\includegraphics[width = 2cm,valign=t,
                              margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt
                              ]{kontext.jpg}}
   &         \includegraphics[width = 2cm,valign=t]{tabel.jpg}
   & \mcA{2}{\includegraphics[width = 2cm,valign=t]{rumgeometri.jpg}}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \cline{2-16}
   & \mcB{2}{\afsnit{Kasser til markedet}}
   & Tabel- tr{\ae}ning
   & \mcB{2}{Under- s{\o}gelse}
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \cline{2-16}
   & $1$--$4$
   & $5$--$9$
   &
   & $116$
   & $117$
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
   Amalie
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &  5
   &  6
   &  7
   &  8
   &  9
   & 10
   & 11
   & 12
   & 13
   & 14 \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**edit:**
in case, that all images have the same parameters (width, align, margins) you can define new command which make shorter code for inserting image in tables:

```
\newcommand\insertimage[1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=22mm,
                     valign=t,
                     margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{#1}
                        }
```

and the use it as follows:

```
   ...
   \hline
     \multirow{9}{=}{\huge\bfseries Uge 8--9}
   & \mcA{2}{\insertimage{kontext.jpg}}
   &         \insertimage{tabel.jpg}
   & \mcA{2}{\insertimage{rumgeometri.jpg}}
   &  5
   &  6
   ...
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope that you will look at that too. (Thank you in advance.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, i will look closely at early night :-) (after few hours). anyway, warning not harm layout. probably is caused by some column width or with complete table width. i need to look in log.file.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, two questions: (i) why you use landscape orientation of paper (is table so tall that it height is close to 410 mm?), (ii) do you really need so many different widths of columns (since the most of differences are negligible, i see that are needed only two widths: one for the first column and second for remaining) .

Comment: (1) The orientation is of general purpose; I'll need this type of structure of my document in other documents as well. (2) I probably don't need all the different column widths but I'm not completely sure. (If you come up with a smart solution, I can always revert it if I really do need a lot of different widths.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, your page layout is, sorry, strange. 2mm width of border? and also A3 paper? for it in landscape orientation your table seems to be to wide. please, check your settings for page layout again and confirm me, that it not contain any error.

Comment: I have now changed the margins but otherwise it is correct.

Comment: i download my answer and test it. i receive only one "bad boxes". in `log` file is indicated with `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 86--86`. it is cell with `. it `\mcB{2}{Under s{\o}gelse}` . it can be removed by `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Under s{\o}gelse}` but table become ugly. it is better to redesign table as is shown in my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

your finding of  "glitch" i can't reproduce completely (as i say in above comment, it doesn't harm your table looks out). after more carefully examine of your table show me some possibilities how to improve it:

- from added package `makecell` is used:

  - macro `makecell` for setting cells with two line text (it removed bad box and vertical center contents in other cell in row)
  - macro `makegapedcells` for add more vertical space about cells' contents
- with determination of column width as fraction of table width the table width is (almost) equal to text width (with this is still neglecting small difference caused by accuracy of calculation)
- since all image has the same width (otherwise they not fit in cells) is sensible use new command for inserting image as i suggested in previous answer

Since redesign of your table take me quite long time and effort and this was not concern of the first version of question, i decided that it is worth to write a new answer.

in *mwe* below i removed all unused definitions and packages from yours *mwe* and add `showframe` package for show page layout (with red lines).

[image]

note: your selected margin is (to my opinion) very unusual. you will have difficulties to print this table (on page border you have a line what make problems to the most of printers).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,
            landscape,
            hmargin = 2mm,
            vmargin = 0mm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{%
    \multicolumn{2}%
                {>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr0.0714\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.06\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}%
                {#1}}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand\insertimage[1]{\includegraphics[width=20mm, valign=t]{#1}}

\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.5pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{
     |>{\RaggedRight\bfseries}%
                   p{\dimexpr0.0714\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.06\arrayrulewidth\relax}
*{2}{|>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr0.0357\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.06\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
     |>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr0.0714\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.06\arrayrulewidth\relax}
*{2}{|>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr0.0357\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.06\arrayrulewidth\relax}}|
*{10}{>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr0.0714\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.06\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
                }
    \hline
Tid     & \mcx{\SI{75}{\minute}}
        & \SI{15}{\minute}
        & \mcx{\SI{45}{\minute}}
        & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16  \\  \hline
Sted    & \mcx{Bog}
        & Mappe
        & \mcx{Bog/comp.}
        & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16  \\  \hline
\multirow{9}{=}{\huge\bfseries Uge 8--9}
        & \mcx{\insertimage{kontext.jpg}}
        &      \insertimage{tabel.jpg}
        & \mcx{\insertimage{rumgeometri.jpg}}
        & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16  \\  \cline{2-16}
   & \mcx{\itshape \makecell{Kasser til\\ markedet}}
   &      \makecell{Tabel-\\ tr{\ae}ning}
   & \mcx{\makecell{Under-\\ s{\o}gelse}}
        & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16  \\  \hline
   & 1 -- 4
   & 5 -- 6
   &
   & 116
   & 117
        & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16  \\  \hline
Amalie
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
        & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```